# Styled-components delay setting property in Nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to implement `styled-components` in a React project with Nextjs. The problem is that, although I can implement and see the styles, there is a small delay when I see it on the browser. First it loadeds the component without style, and 22ms later the style is applied. What I'm doing wrong? 
Thanks

Here is my code!

pages/index.js

```
import React from "react";
import Home from "../components/home/index";


const index = () => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
        <Home />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default index;
```

components/home.js

```
import React from "react";
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Title = styled.h1`
  color: red;
`;

function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Title>My First Next.js Page</Title>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

babel.rc

```
{
  "presets": ["next/babel"],
  "plugins": [["styled-components", { "ssr": true }]]
}
```

pages/_document.js

```
import Document from 'next/document';
import { ServerStyleSheet } from 'styled-components';

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet();
    const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;

    try {
      ctx.renderPage = () =>
        originalRenderPage({
          enhanceApp: App => props => sheet.collectStyles(<App {...props} />)
        });

      const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);
      return {
        ...initialProps,
        styles: (
          <>
            {initialProps.styles}
            {sheet.getStyleElement()}
          </>
        )
      };
    } finally {
      sheet.seal();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens because your styles are being applied client side. You will need to follow [this modification](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-styled-components/pages/_document.js) from the examples provided by Next.js.

You actually need to create a [custom Document](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document), collect all your styles from your `<App />` component using `ServerStyleSheet` provided by `styled-components` and apply them server side, so when your app reaches the client, the styles will already be there.

As they also state on the `README` of this example:

> For this purpose we are extending the `<Document />` and injecting the server side rendered styles into the `<head>`, and also adding the babel-plugin-styled-components (which is required for server side rendering).

I hope this solves your issue.

Comment: Thanks Michalis, I alredy have a _document.js file. I edited the qs. You can see it there.

Comment: Hmm this is weird. If you made any changes based on the example I provided, please restart your app. Any edit on `_document.js` file is not applied till you run `yarn dev` again.

Comment: Michalis I follow your example step by step and now it works! I don t know by.. I would have to investigate it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Happy I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of the _document file:

```
import Document, { Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document';
import { ServerStyleSheet } from 'styled-components';

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  static getInitialProps({ renderPage }) {
    const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet();

    function handleCollectStyles(App) {
      return props => {
        return sheet.collectStyles(<App {...props} />);
      };
    }

    const page = renderPage(App => handleCollectStyles(App));
    const styleTags = sheet.getStyleElement();
    return { ...page, styleTags };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <html>
        <Head>{this.props.styleTags}</Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </html>
    );
  }
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: I German, thanks! I try your example and the loader time reducer form 22 to 11 ms, but the problem still there...

Comment: Oh that's great, do you have a repo of your code? I can take a look to check the issue.

Comment: I found the issue, the file should be named **_document.js** and not **_documents.js** just rename the file and paste my code into your **_document.js** and it should work! I cloned your code and made those changes and it worked! let me know.

Comment: No problem :) Glad i helped!